# Catching twisted.internet.error.NoRouteError generated from Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

My scrapy application is trying to download more than 20k pages in single run. I want to be sure about its stability. The internet connection of my machine is not persistent, it starts to give connection lost after a while:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/virtualenvs/XXX/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1126, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/Users/XXX/virtualenvs/XXX/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/Users/XXX/virtualenvs/XXX/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.NoRouteError: No route to host: 51: Network is unreachable.
2016-07-23 06:30:31 scrapy ERROR : Error downloading <GET http://XXX>
```

I overcome this situation in mysql side by trying until connection is restablish:

```
while True:
try:
    c.execute(query)
    inserted_id = c.lastrowid

    if commit:
        self._db_conn.commit()

    break  # Break, done with job

except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    error_code = e.args[0]

    if error_code == 1213 or error_code == 2006 or error_code == 2005:  # If it is a connection error
        time.sleep(trial * 5)
        trial += 1  # Connection lost Exception occurred retrying
        self.logger.error(
            msg="Error occurred while inserting the database. Trial count: {}, Error Code: {}, Error Message: {}".format(
                trial,
                e.args[0],
                str(e)
            )
        )
```

I want to implement similar approach for Scrapy page requests. Do I have to use downloader middleware or should I write a error callback function?